# Does macroparadise no longer work from the command line?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise, scalameta

I am trying to start using the paradise macro plugin, so I have been beginning with the identity macro example from:

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html

However, when I try to use the identity annotation I get

```
error: enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations
```

As you would expect if the plugin isn't loaded.  However, I am following the instructions from

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html

But when I invoke:

```
scalac -Xplugin:paradise_2.12.8-2.1.1.jar -Xshow-phases
```

I do not see the `macroparadise` phase:

```
    phase name  id  description
    ----------  --  -----------
        parser   1  parse source into ASTs, perform simple desugaring
         namer   2  resolve names, attach symbols to named trees
packageobjects   3  load package objects
         typer   4  the meat and potatoes: type the trees
        patmat   5  translate match expressions
        ...
```

However, if I instead do

```
scalac -Xplugin:paradise_2.12.8-2.1.1.jar -Xplugin-list
```

I get

```
macroparadise - Empowers production Scala compiler with latest macro developments
```

So I really confused as to what step I'm missing here?  Is there some new command-line argument I'm missing?  Is using sbt required?

Comment: I did some experimentation with sbt and was able to get that to work as expected.  But our build process is really not amenable to using sbt, so I'd really like to be able to get this work with the command-line.

Comment: I just discovered this open issue: https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/106

Comment: Given that there has been no progress on that issue in over a year, I think my only hope is that with 2.13 very close to release, I can reasonably switch to developing on 2.13 (which is supposed to have paradise built in) and hope that will resolve my issue.

Comment: Oh and then there is also https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/99.  So clearly the developers must only ever use sbt.

Comment: It looks like using ` -Ymacro-annotations` on 2.13-M5 works fine, so I guess I'll have to see how difficult upgrading proves to be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some developer oversight, but the plugin is working this way in my case - I use `scala-maven-plugin` and this maven plugin uses command line call to new java process.

Both symptoms are present: `-Xplugin-list` shows the plugin and `-Xshow-phases` does not show any changes

Note that you need to use separate subproject / submodule with macros, they can only be used after they are compiled.